# Ordering (Language C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort a struct from a number (code) that the user will enter and I'm using bubble sort for this. I want the program to print all the data sorted by the number (code) but it only sorts the number (code). Can someone help me sort the other elements from the number (code)?

CODE:

```
#include locale.h  
#include stdio.h  
#include string.h  

int main(void) {  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");  
    int aux = 0, i, j;  
    struct dados {  
        int codigo;  
        char titulo[40];  
    } livro[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        printf("Código %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &livro[i].codigo);  
        fflush(stdin);  
        printf("Título %d: ", i);
        gets(livro[i].titulo);  
    }  
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {  
            if (livro[i].codigo > livro[j].codigo) {  
                aux = livro[i].codigo;  
                livro[i].codigo = livro[j].codigo;  
                livro[j].codigo = aux;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        printf("%d %s\n", livro[i].codigo, livro[i].titulo);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in that language. If that's not possible, you should post at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Sidenote: `fflush(stdin);` -> undefined bahviour (don't!)

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: You need a new source of learning C. Your current one is crap and teaches you incorrect practice.

Comment: @GustavoFrancoFadel: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- There are syntax errors in you `#include` lines.
- The reading loop is incorrect: you do not check the return value of `scanf()`, you use the obsolete function `gets()` that will just read the pending newline left by `scanf()` in the input stream.  The data read into the array will be incorrect, and the behavior is probably undefined.
- `fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior.
- In the sort loop, you only swap the value of the `codigo` field, not the array element. You are corrupting the data. You should instead swap the structures.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(void) {  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");  // probably incorrect?
    int i, j;  
    struct dados {  
        int codigo;  
        char titulo[40];  
    } livro[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        printf("Código %d: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &livro[i].codigo) != 1)
            return 1;
        printf("Título %d: ", i);
        if (scanf(" %39[^\n]", livro[i].titulo) != 1)
            return 1;
    }  
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {  
            if (livro[i].codigo > livro[j].codigo) {  
                struct dados aux = livro[i];  
                livro[i] = livro[j];  
                livro[j] = aux;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
        printf("%d %s\n", livro[i].codigo, livro[i].titulo);  
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the entire structure, not only its first member:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < n_livros; i++)  
{  
    for(unsigned j = i + 1; j < n_livros; j++)  
    {  
        if(livro[i].codigo > livro[j].codigo)  
        {  
            struct dados aux = livro[i];  
            livro[i] = livro[j];  
            livro[j] = aux;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

As Olaf commented, `flush(stdin);` is Undefined Behavior, just don't do that.
Also, note that `gets()` was first deprecated  in C99 and then removed from C11. You should use a function that performs bounds checking, like `fgets()` and always inspect its (and `scanf()`'s) return value.